# Table creation false in Azure Storage using java

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage

I created a java program for create a new table people at the Azure Storage. but i could not able to create a new table.This is my Java code.

```
 CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =    CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

   CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.createCloudTableClient();

   String tableName = "people";
   CloudTable cloudTable = new CloudTable(tableName,tableClient);
//A below line Produce the False.
   cloudTable.createIfNotExists();
```

Can someone Explain this?

Thank u

Comment: Any logs and exceptions?

Comment: there is no logs and exception. System .out.println(cloudTable.createIfNotExists(); Result is False;

Comment: This is expected behavior. If the table already exists in your storage account, this method will return false. It returns true if the table does not exist.

Comment: If i execute the list of tables in the container program.it will display all the created tables.but table is not there at the storage account.